# How to count active child element of ul in react?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

```
<ul className="menu">
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
   <li class="hidden">Hidden when screen size is of mobile</li>
   <li>4 li item</li>
</ul>
```

I wish to count no. of `<li>`. so when the screen size changes from desktop to mobile the count should decrease by one to a total of 3 `active <li>`.

document.getElementByClassName('menu').length does not works.

Jquery is also an option , but is there react way of doing things.

I have a array of pics which I want to display,but can show only 7 and rest should reveal on click.Now when the screen size changes to mobile only 3 can be shown rest onclick. 
Its like : 7+1(b) for desktop and 3+1(b) for mobile. b hold the no. of remaining pictures.

Comment: How about `getElementByClassName` with an additional `s` ?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.menu > li').length`

Comment: what is the top level react component in this case? how are you rendering the list elements? where are the contents for list elements coming from?

Comment: content is coming through an api...which contains array of image urls..
rendering them through map function

Answer (score 3):

If you attach the `.menu` element to a `ref`, you can retrieve it without resorting to query selectors, therefore keeping your component isolated.

With `ref` in place

`<ul ref={el => this.menu = el} className"...">`

You can then do

`this.menu.childNodes.length`

Documentation links:

- React Ref attribute: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
- ChildNodes: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp

Comment: thanskk...this works...sorry couldn't vote up as i am newbie...still to gain some reputation

Comment: should a listener to catch hidden <li> on mobile resolution...
i am trying to caluculate no of nodes dynamically as screen size changes.

Comment: You can add a resize listener like this `window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeIframe);` and perform the calculators you need